# How can I use Julia in Jupyter lab, MacBook M1?

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter-lab, apple-m1

Julia REPL run well in my M1 mac, but I can't use it in jupyter lab.
I tried same way as in Win10, just like below.

```
using Pkg
ENV["JUPYTER"]="Users/(user name)/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter.exec"
Pkg.build("IJulia")
Pkg.add("IJulia")
```

The path in Win10 was

```
ENV["JUPYTER"]="C:\\Users\\(user name)\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\jupyter.exe"
```

But the `jupyter` file is located in different path in mac, so I changed the path.

After this setting, Julia symbol appears right in jupyter lab launcher, but I get some error message when I click.

```
Error Starting Kernel
Unhandled error
Unhandled error
```

What's the right way to set Julia in JupyterLab in osX, M1?